# Regex: Arabic word boundary

Tags: regex, arabic

I have this **text**

```
RT @za3eim9: الهلاليين : أجْسادَ مُتفرقه وَقلبً واحد..
```

and this **pattern** (which is a substring of the above text)

```
ساد
```

**Is the pattern a word? That is, should `"\b" + pattern + "\b"` match the text?**

---

Apparently, on the left of the pattern, I have this character (invisible in Sublime Text) below

```
ْ
```

And on the right of the pattern, I have this character (also invisible in my text editor)

```
َ
```

P.S. Searching the pattern (Control/Command + F) in the browser does not show a match. For me, copying the above strings in Sublime Text shows a match.

---

*I'm asking because Java and Python Regexes gave different answers. It really helps if I could know in advance whether the answer is positive or negative.*

Comment: well it seems not just java :D I tested it on regex101 and it works only if i choose python. i am not sure what would be the best way to get it but i would like to know the answer too :D

Comment: it works when i remove `\b` for java, python and other languages